# How could I duplicate this example?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I am relatively new to LaTeX and have made a few (beautiful) documents with it. However, I ran into a brick wall today, I cannot seem for the life of me be able to replicate the example shown below. I have tried searching for this specific problem, but with no success. Therefore, I ask the community for support!

[image]

Comment: A very warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Go ahead and show us what you tried, `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}` and I am sure you will have an answer in short order.  See _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Comment: Hi! I will create a good MWE next time, I understand that that works the best for all of the curious folks that would love to help me resolve my question.

Comment: Looking forward to your next question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one suggestion with `pmatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
D_{i,t} = \begin{pmatrix}
\ln(\text{Deal value}) \\
\text{Loan Maturity} \\
\text{Loan Type} \\
\text{Credit Rating of the Loan} \\
\text{Coupon Rate}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If one wants to avoid the use of `\text` in each row, then a `tabular` could be used. Note the use of `@{}` to remove spacing at the start and end of each row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
D_{i,t} = \left(\begin{tabular}{ @{} c @{} }
$\ln(\text{Deal value})$ \\
Loan Maturity \\
Loan Type \\
Credit Rating of the Loan \\
Coupon Rate
\end{tabular}\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I  read the first line as the logarithm of deal value, hence the use of `\ln`, if I misread it, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, I was so thrilled with the quick answer that I completely forgot to thank you! It worked like a charm, thanks again!